# Are there more explicit commands/toolbars and feedback for Eclipse for Android?

Tags: eclipse, workflow, toolbar, feedback

I'm new to Eclipse. I may need a better understanding or a plugin that would provide me with features described below. While doing some Android development, and I while making changes to my code at one point Eclipse warned me that this emulator doesn't support hot-swapping and if I want to disconnect. I'm used to see status in either the toolbar or in some log from Visual Studio. Is there a way to see this feedback in Eclipse?

My problem is that there are quite much implicit stuff in eclipse I would like get feedback of and control, like whether I'm

- connected or not to a device,
- if I'm attached to a process on it or not with debugger,
- some kind of build log with a timestamp so I know it happened,
- the automatic uninstalling and installing of the project on the device
- which project is "active" ("featured") in "Run" and "Debug" buttons/configurations

Is there a plugin that can give me explicit commands over these automatic features? Like a toolbar or command. What I would expect of this tool:

- be able to indicate the current status (eg. currently connected or not)
- gives me control to eg. connect
- gives me control to eg. disconnect

Preferably on a toolbar, as I know some of these are available as menu commands.
Furthermore I tried to configure my toolbar by `Window` menu -> `Customize perspective...`, but pin-pointing the features I want made my Eclipse put empty space up for the buttons I disabled, and next time I got to the same config screen it got the checkboxes wrong and displayed some stuff active what was actually disabled.